# How to reset a specified system.threading.timer VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timer

New to programming and this is my very first post! Very exciting:D

Thank you all in advance for sharing your expertise.

I would like to be able to somehow reference the earlier created timer and to be able to extend it (call Change upon its instance perhaps?) on Button2_Click. Please take a look at the code below:

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1

    Public Timer As Timer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer = New Timer(AddressOf TimerHandler, 123, 5000, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimerHandler(ByVal timerID As Object)
        MsgBox("Timer Elapsed!!!!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        '''''''''''''''reset timer "123"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `Threading.Timer` at all.  Use a `Timers.Timer`, which can be added to the form in the designer or created in code.  Handle the `Elapsed` event, use the `Interval` property to determine the time between events and use the `Start` and `Stop` methods to do the obvious.

Comment: Thank you for that. I might be missing the obvious, however is there an ability to reference threading.timer by ID or anything that I can set to reference later? The example above is over simplified. I took the problem as I encountered it and trying to find a solution before implementing it in the main code. The program would create as many timers as it needs to, based on other events, and I have to have an ability to create timer IDs based on lets say hash table keys.... which there will be many.

Comment: If you want to be able to access one of multiple objects, be they `Timers` or otherwise, then you need to store those objects somewhere.  You would need a collection of some sort rather than just a single `Timer` variable.  You could use a `List` or `Dictionary` or whatever provides the appropriate access.